# Multithreading problem(UI not updated)

Tags: objective-c, iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch

Hey, I have a problem in Multithreading.
To describe this, I have two threads.
On main thread I have some logic
And on another thread, I have a logic and some logic to UI which will update UI.
What I want to do is that I want to call some method after the UI on another thread is updated.
I think I am supposed to use NSOperationQueue or something. or background queue.
but I have read the concurrency programming and threading guide and I still have no idea how to do it.

So how to do it so that I can call a method after a thread is finished?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never touch the UI from any thread other than the main thread. Two easy ways of sending messsages between threads:

performSelector:

```
[someObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(someSelector) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Notifications:

```
NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"myNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(postNotification:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:NO];
```

You can of course also use an NSOperationQueue and Key-Value-Observe the job's finished property, but unless you'd need it for other reasons it just adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: NSNotifications are received on the same thread they were posted from, so the second example needs to use performSelectorOnMainThread: as well. (And one small typo @selector(postNotification) is missing a ':'.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure KVO runs on the same thread too, so you're down to performSelectorOnMainThread:

Comment: @Vincent Gable:You don't need a colon on the end of the selector.  From the docs: The method should not have a significant return value and should take a single argument of type id, **or no arguments** .  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-CJBEHAEF

Comment: Vincent, you're right of course - just forgot to write out onMainThread. The missing colon was intentional though, as JeremyP says.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that '@selector(postNotification)' should be '@selector(postNotification:)', because -postNotification: and -postNotification are two different methods. The colon is part of the name.

Running the code,
'*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNotificationCenter postNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d13a70''

Answer (score 0):

Here's the nicest way, if you're using iOS 4.0:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // update the UI here...
});
```